# Can you explicitly use a constructor overload?

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading, ambiguous-grammar, disambiguation

If I have 2 constructor overloads

```
calculations(double vector, double angle);
calculations(double horizontalVector, double verticalVector);
```

How can I ensure the compiler specifically uses one of the overloads that I choose (as each of them do different things behind the scenes)?

Comment: They are the same constructor, not overloads. Variable names don't matter.

Comment: That is not an overload, the argument name does not contribute to overload resolution.

Comment: Ah okay,  because the variable name is a dummy. Is there anyway then, that I can use the second one?

Comment: Disambiguate with a third argument or use a different function name (or template parameter).

Comment: I think you should take a step back to your design instead, and rethink the need for two constructors using the exact same arguments.

Comment: `that I can use the second one? ` It's _the same_ one. I believe you want to research tag dispatching.

Comment: You can use "static constructors", as for `struct Angle { static Angle Degree(double); static Angle Radian(double); /*..*/};`.

Comment: How do you repesent a vector as a `double`? Are those "vector" parameters actually polar and cartesian coordinates?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have overloads, the types needs to be different. One way to do this is the so called whole value idiom.

Make a `struct` for each parameters: a vector (watching out for potential name clashes), angle and so on.

The you will have two different constructors.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your parameters are actually polar and cartesian coordinates rather than vectors,

```
calculations(double length, double angle);
calculations(double x_coordinate, double y_coordinate);
```

you can abstract those into types,

```
struct Polar { double length, angle; };
struct Cartesian {double x, y; };
```

and overload

```
calculations(const Polar& p);
calculations(const Cartesian& c);
```

and then

```
calculations c1(Polar{1,1});
calculations c2(Cartesian{1,1});
```

Comment: @einpoklum: it is the issue of doctorlove answer, missing example. So it is not clear, but her answer is more something like `calculations(Length length, Angle angle); calculations(X x, Y y);`.

Answer (score 2):

To provide different functions with same parameters you can use tag dispatching, where you provide unused parameter to do overloading.

```
struct Calculations {
  struct UseTwoVectors {};
  Calculations(double vector, double angle);
  Calculations(double horizontalVector, double verticalVector, const UseTwoVectors&);
};
int main() {
    Calculations c(1, 2);
    Calculations d(1, 2, Calculations::UseTwoVectors());
}
```

Overall I do not know what these arguments represent - I suspect there is something wrong with abstraction in your code. You could take a different approach and make a class from your parameters.

```
struct VectorAngle {
    double vector, angle;
};
struct TwoVectors {
    double horizontalVector, verticalVector;
};
struct Calculations {
  Calculations(const VectorAngle& v);
  Calculations(const TwoVectors& v);
};
int main() {
    Calculations c(VectorAngle{1, 2});
    Calculations d(TwoVectors{1, 2});
};
```